Example of 3-solvable group of large 3-length
I would like to construct examples of $3$-solvable groups with large $3$-length. That means that the Sylow $3$-subgroups need to be large in a sense. Is there any general construction of such examples? Preferably, the examples should not be solvable.

The Suzuki simple groups have orders not divisible by $3$, so you could take iterated wreath products of $3$-groups with Suzuki groups, such as $S_1 \wr P_1 \wr S_2 \wr P_2 \wr \cdots $ where the $S_i$ is Suzuki groups and the $P_i$ are $3$-groups.

Thank you. If $G$ is such an example, is there a way to explicitly determine $O_{3'3}(G)$? I am willing to settle with $S_i$ being solvable as well.

Yes, $O_{3'3}(G)$ is the group $S_1^k.P_1^l$ for some $k$ and $l$, where the $S_1^k$ is the base group of the whole thing and the $C_1^l$ is the base group of $P_` \wr S_2 \wr \cdots$.
